# Switching ui-router states when clicking or scrolling to page sections

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a huge page with four sections that is intended to be used as "single page checkout" for the shop.

```
[Header]
...
[Section 1: delivery address form]
[Section 2: payment address form ]
[Section 3: payment option form]
[Section 4: flags / agreements]
...
[Footer]
```

Each section contains a form. The requirement is to have those four sections to be mapped onto angular `ui-router` states (the idea is to use existing router configuration, which previously used for "multiple page checkout" when each of sections is placed on different page/state).

**Is it possible to switch states when user clicks / scrolls (checking if the section is in viewport?) to a particular section on the same page? Is there any good example of how this can be implemented?**

In the project I have following versions:

```
{
  "angular": "~1.5.0",
  "angular-route": "~1.5.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to "switch state" in the page anyway? You can have multiple named views in the same page [as described here.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Here is a simple plunker to demo the above:

https://plnkr.co/edit/fhK8wix4Ve5nCiKKKejX?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div ui-view="first"></div>
  <div ui-view="second"></div>
  <div ui-view="third"></div>      
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('page', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      'first': { template: '<div>1</div>' },
      'second': { template: '<div>2</div>' },
      'third': { template: '<div>3</div>' }
    }
  })
})
```

Plunker changing view with button click: https://plnkr.co/edit/MzaeQMkSJiev2Vsfpx8c?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 
The requirement however is to map existing states to page sections. In other words, what was state before should now be a section - content inside each section plus logic with navigation among them should be preserved. Is it possible to achieve that without modifying existing states configuration?

Comment: I'd imagine the changes would be pretty small, mainly just changing the existing states to be 'views' of a single state. As for the navigation, you can't really use `ui-sref` or `$state.go` since the views aren't actual states - you can, however, scroll to a selected view using `$anchorScroll`. I've added a plunker to demonstrate the 'navigation'.